# How to make/build project against one version of a library but its dependencies against a different version of that library?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, dynamic-linking, cmakelists-options

I have workspace structure as shown below. It involves `PROJ` for project, `TPL` for third party library and `DEP-PROJ` for dependency project (and `ws` for workspace). I have also specified their dependencies inside brackets, next to them.

```
ws   
├── opencv34
│   ├── opencv
│   └── opencv_contrib
├── opencv44
|   ├── opencv
|   └── opencv_contrib
├── DEP-PROJ (opencv 3.4)
└── PROJ (DEP-PROJ, opencv 4.4)
    └── TPL (opencv 4.4)
```

I have built both versions of opencv with `cmake ..` and `make -j6` commands. But did not run `make install`.

Next, `DEP-PROJ` has following lines in its CMakeLists.txt (notice `OPENCV3_DIR`):

```
set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV3_DIR})
find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED)
```

Before doing `cmake` in `DEP-PROJ/build` directory, I run `export OPENCV3_DIR=/ws/opencv34/opencv/build`, so that `cmake` succeeds.

Next, `PROJ` has following lines in its CMakeLists.txt (notice `OPENCV4_DIR`):

```
set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})
find_package(OpenCV 4.4 REQUIRED)
```

Next, before doing `cmake` in `PROJ/build` directory, I run `export OPENCV4_DIR=/ws/opencv34/opencv/build`, so that `cmake` succeeds.

Before doing `cmake` in `PROJ/build` directory, I run `export OPENCV4_DIR=/ws/opencv44/opencv/build`, so that `cmake` succeeds.

This cause cmake to succeed, but make fails with error:

```
fatal error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory
```

It seems that doing make inside `PROJ` rebuilds `DEP-PROJ`. However, CMakeLists.txt of `PROJ` sets `OpenCV_DIR` to `opencv44` directory. This makes `DEP-PROJ` build fail giving above error.

To avoid this, I run `make install` inside `/ws/opencv34/opencv/build`. This lets `DEP-PROJ` find opencv 3.4 from `/usr` directory and `PROJ` references opencv 4.4 from `/ws/opencv44/opencv/build` directory leading to successfully building `PROJ`.

However, I feel its a bit hacky way to resolve this (doing `make install` in opencv 3.4 and not doing it in opencv 4.4). What is correct way to do this? How can I avoid rebuilding `DEP-PROJ` while building `PROJ`? or build it against `/ws/opencv34/opencv/build` (instead of opencv in `/usr`) along with building `PROJ` against `/ws/opencv44/opencv/build`?

PS: I am noob in cmake.

Comment: this is not specific to opencv. this is a general problem of *dynamic linking*. with static linking, this would be a non-issue. however, legal issues prevent many libraries from being linked statically.

Comment: But there has to be some cmake config or something else, that is usually used to solve such things?

Comment: without reading the entire question, let's say A depends on B and C2, but B also depends on C1. do you expect to run a single build that does everything, or do you build B ***separately***, so you can then ***use*** it in the build of A?

Comment: Anything works for me. I first built B separately. It worked. But then while building A, it fails with error: `opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory`. Turns out that function is there in C1, but not in C2. Ideally, it should NOT have tried to build B again against C2 as a part of building A, instead it should have used already built B while building A. But that does not seem to happen.

Comment: There are multiple possible link issues here, @ChristophRackwitz, but none of them cause the particular *compilation* error the OP reports.

Comment: @MsA, chances of making this work are poor, but what chances there are are tied up in the details of the software and build system.  It's unlikely that you can put those in a form suitable for an SO question.  Your best bet is to figure out how to use the same version of OpenCV for everything.  Your next best bet is probably to build the dependency independently, but there are multiple reasons why that might not suffice.  You should consider engaging an expert to work on this project, and I don't mean by asking questions here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the error `opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory` seems related to linking since cv.h is there in OpenCV 3 and no more there in OpenCV4. So it seems `DEP-PORJ` indeed seem to get re-compiled against OpenCV4 while building `PROJ`. **Q1.** Does this detail help to imagine any solution? I indeed tried to build `DEP-PROJ` with OpenCV 4. But it did not. I tried to replace imports for cv.h with equivalent header in OpenCV 4, but then it resulted in cascaded code changes. So, making `DEP-PROJ` work with OpenCV 4 does not seem to be easy task. (continued ...)

Comment: (... continued) Regarding "build the dependency independently", I am indeed able to build `DEP-PROJ` independently with OpenCV 3, but during building `PROJ`, it seems to rebuild `DEP-PROJ` against OpenCV 4. **Q2.** Is this normal / default CMake behavior, or am missing somethin? How do I fix this? that is, make `PROJ` build use `DEP-PROJ` already built against OpenCV3 instead of rebuilding it against OpenCV4. Any hint / web link  discussing related CMake config? **Q3.** Regarding " there are multiple reasons why that might not suffice" - any detail / quick hint / web link discussing the same?

Comment: @MsA, headers such as `opencv/cv.h` are processed by the compiler, not the linker. They are not involved in linking.  This has nothing to do with whether one project is rebuilt during the build of the other.

Comment: @MsA, when I suggest building `DEP-PROJ` independently, I mean to imply that you also persuade the build of `PROJ` to *use* that independently-built result instead of rebuilding.  How you might do that depends on your tools, but it might involve installing `DEP-PROJ` to the system.

Comment: @MsA, there is no particular "normal CMake behavior" at the level of abstraction at which you are describing your problem.  CMake is a program that does what you tell it to do.

Comment: Reasons why using an independently built `DEP-PROJ` might not suffice all revolve around lack of build-time and / or run-time isolation of the two versions of OpenCV.  Whether the OpenCV libs are built as shared or static libraries, there are several patterns of details that could lead to one project trying to call the functions of the wrong OpenCV version at runtime.  It is also possible that `DEP-PROJ` `#include`s `opencv/cv.h` in its own public headers, which `PROJ` needs to use, thereby making that file required regardless. [...]

Comment: [...] It is also possible that `PROJ` and `DEP-PROJ` need to exchange data structures that differ based on the OpenCV version.  If you were lucky, this would manifest as a compile-time error, but if you were unlucky it could manifest as mysterious, weird runtime behavior.

Comment: I never said or supposed that it would be easy to upgrade `DEP-PROJ` to OpenCV 4.  If it's *your* project then that might nevertheless be worthwhile.  If not, then perhaps someone else has already done so.  And if not that, then maybe you should look for an alternative.

Comment: Yes difference in OpenCV data structures will be deal breaking issue. Super thanks for all detailed inputs. Couple of last questions: **(1)** Though I dont like hard coding, will hard coding path in `DEP-PROJ`'s CMakeLists.txt help: `find_package(OpenCV 3.4 REQUIRED PATHS /ws/opencv34/opencv/build)`? **(2)** Can CMake's `ExternalProject_Add` module help use independently built `DEP-PROJ` while building `PROJ`? (cmake noob again)

Comment: ***will hard coding path in DEP-PROJ's CMakeLists.txt help[...]?*** -- it might help get a successful build.  It would not at all address any of the overall issues with dual OpenCV dependencies.  ***Can CMake's `ExternalProject_Add` module help use independently built `DEP-PROJ` while building `PROJ`?*** -- probably not.  It might change the nature of the build dependency, but it does not get you an independent build.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: mixing multiple versions of a single library in the same process on UNIX *doesn't* work, just give up!

---

You appear to be building for UNIX.

Unlike on Windows, a UNIX shared library is *not* self-contained -- it is subject to symbol interposition and symbol collisions.

Also, OpenCV versions 3.4 and 4.4 define the same symbols, and are *not* ABI-compatible.

Taken together the two statements above mean that *IF* you manage to link your project dynamically with versions 3.4 and 4.4 of OpenCV, you are almost guaranteed to have inexplicable crashes, memory corruption, and more.

(If you try to link your project with archive versions instead, you will most likely fail with multiple symbol definition instead.)